# How to connect to Ethereum Mainnet from a Mobile App?

Tags: go-ethereum, rpc

I have tested with various private Ethereum chains and test ones using Web3 and RPC calls to a node from React. I am working on connecting to the mainnet for Ethereum with the same principle.

If I have a mobile app, should I connect to a light node on the phone or a service such as infura to main security for connecting to the public Ethereum network?

Any comments are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Running a local node on the mobile phone is too intensive.
Actually what you can do is to connect to a remote node from the mobile app. This node can be provided by Infura or a node running on your own remote server.